# Erro com valores duplicados no AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Estou com um problema de valores duplicados no AngularJS, no meu JSON vai ter sempre categorias repetidas, no `ng-repeat` eu usei o `track by $index` mas o erro persistiu.

O código do meu controller:

```
angular.module('starter').controller('Guia', function($scope, $http) {
  var grp = {};
  $http.get('js/lugares.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.categories = data;
    angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(item){
        var chr = item.categoria.charAt(0);
        if(!grp.hasOwnProperty(chr)) grp[chr] = [];
        grp[chr].push(item.categoria);
     })
  });
  $scope.grp = grp;
});
```

Meu HTML está assim:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="(k,v) in grp track by $index">
  <div class="item item-divider">{{k}}</div>
  <a ng-href="#/categoria-guia" class="item" ng-repeat="i in v">{{i}}</a>
</div>
```

E o JSON assim:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "nome": "Agência MegaDigital",
    "categoria": "Tecnologia e Informática"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Bar do Grego",
    "categoria": "Bares e Restaurantes"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Anselmo Lanches",
    "categoria": "Bares e Restaurantes"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Internet de Dimas",
    "categoria": "Tecnologia e Informática"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "nome": "Banca Caixa Postal",
    "categoria": "Banca de Revista"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "nome": "Xerox Central",
    "categoria": "Papelaria e Escritório"
  }
]
```

O resultado final exibe uma lista de todas as categorias numa lista ordenada pela letra inicial da categoria.

Comment: O único problema que estás a ter é a ordenação pela letra inicial?

Comment: Não, em relação a ordenação eu já consegui fazer e está tudo certo, o problema é que como tenho categorias repetidas, aparece esse erro aqui: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altemberg, pelo que posso ver, você está utilizando um objeto `var grp = {};` que possui um array `grp[chr] = []`.

Você criou no objeto `grp`, uma chave `b` que recebe a categoria **dentro de uma array**, resultaria em algo como isto:

```
 grp = {
     b: ["Banca de Revista", "Bares e Restaurantes"], // ** Array **
     p: ["Papelaria e Escritório"],
     t: ["Tecnologia e Informática"]
 }
```

Até aí tudo bem, agora vamos resolver o problema da repetição:

```
 if(grp[chr].indexOf(item.categoria) === -1) grp[chr].push(item.categoria)
 // Só acrescentar o novo valor se ele ainda não existir
```

### Funcionando:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var grp = {}; 
  var data = [{
    "id": 0,
    "nome": "Agência MegaDigital",
    "categoria": "Tecnologia e Informática"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "nome": "Bar do Grego",
    "categoria": "Bares e Restaurantes"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "nome": "Anselmo Lanches",
    "categoria": "Bares e Restaurantes"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "nome": "Internet de Dimas",
    "categoria": "Tecnologia e Informática"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "nome": "Banca Caixa Postal",
    "categoria": "Banca de Revista"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "nome": "Xerox Central",
    "categoria": "Papelaria e Escritório"
  }];
  $scope.categories = data; 
  angular.forEach($scope.categories, function(item) {
    var chr = item.categoria.charAt(0);
    if (!grp.hasOwnProperty(chr)) grp[chr] = []; // Criando uma chave no OBJETO (chr), e essa chave possui um ARRAY
    if(grp[chr].indexOf(item.categoria) === -1) grp[chr].push(item.categoria); // Ainda utilizando o array
  })
  $scope.grp = grp;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="list" ng-repeat="(k,v) in grp">
    <div class="item item-divider">{{k}}</div>
    <br>
    <a ng-href="#/categoria-guia" class="item" ng-repeat="i in v">{{i}}<br></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Samir, apareceu o seguinte erro: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: {}

Vou editar minha pergunta acima e colocar também o código do controller para você ter uma noção melhor do meu problema, tudo bem?

Comment: @AltembergAndrade, fica bem melhor mesmo.

Comment: já fiz a edição, dê olhadinha aí por favor.

Comment: @AltembergAndrade, olhe a edição, veja se ficou claro

Comment: Vou ser bem sincero, me perdi um pouco em relação ao objeto e ao array. Como posso colocar o ng-repeat no array grp[chr] como você disse? Desculpe se isso parecer algo muito simples ou obvio, mas é que acabei um livro de angular agora a pouco e estou tentando criar uma aplicação para ir estudando e colocando tudo em prática.

Comment: @AltembergAndrade, Olhe a edição, agora está funcionando... Imagino que agora foi rsrs. Desculpe a demora, estava um pouco ocupado. Era algo bem simples, acredito que eu estava me atrapalhando antes.

Comment: Agora foi! E consegui entender o código melhor agora kkkk. Muito obrigado, Samir.